# Highstock show avegrage values of selected Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highstocks library and trying to compute Average of Y values on Graph. this value is to be dynamic ie everytime user zooms in or changes slider it should recompute average of Y values over selected timestamp region.
I tried this in fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/0tfkfh2v/12/). But it gives values of x { timestamp} also it doesnot provide Y values for selected x range.

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function (e) {
            computeAvg(e);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Better is catch a [redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) event. Additionally you can try to use this plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/34/Dynamic%20Weighted%20Average%20plugin

Comment: @SebastianBochan  I tried selection event in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/0tfkfh2v/13/. but it gives only values on xAxis that too min and max, what I require is avergae of y values for selected x range in timestamp

Comment: In your code there is no calculation of average anywhere, is correct demo ?

Comment: actually in selection event , I am not getting y values , so was not able to compute avg. I require y values  which is not available

Comment: Let me know what is wrong with that plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/pw4fwdjm/18/ ?

Comment: the problem is that plugin gives average of two series for a particular value of x . For example on 18 Aug it shows average of two values , but In my case I have only one series , suppose user has selected data range from Aug 15 - Aug 30 , then I require averge of y values that fall in this range, this average needs to be dynamic depending upon user selection range it needs to be updated in subtitle of graph

Comment: So catch a afterSetExtremes and then use [addPlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine) to draw a average line.

Comment: I added afterSetExtremes  event , but that gives min and max on x axis , as stated in my question fiddle . I want average values of Y for selected X region , if you could update your response in fiddle , that would be helpful. thanks

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0tfkfh2v/14/

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for fiddle , it works fine but one issue , it computes the sum and count value twice, once you zoom in graph to 1 or 2 bar , you see twice the count , values getting repeated , I think loop to calculate is running twice but not sure why ,

Comment: I forget to exclude navigator serie, fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0tfkfh2v/16/

Comment: thanks a lot , it worked

Comment: I added that as answer, so you can mark that as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch redraw() event and prepare function which gets extremes from axis. Next step is iterate over all points to find which are visible. If yes, then add this point to sum. Last step is divide sum by amount of points.

```
function computeAvg() {
        var chart = this,
            series = chart.series,
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
            min = extremes.min,
            max = extremes.max,
            plotLine = chart.get('avgLine'),
            sum = 0,
            count = 0;

        Highcharts.each(series, function (serie, i) {
            if(serie.name !== 'Navigator') {
                Highcharts.each(serie.data, function (point, j) {
                    if (point.x >= min && point.x <= max) {
                        sum += point.y;
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        yAxis.removePlotLine('avgLine');
        yAxis.addPlotLine({
            value: (sum/count),
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            id: 'avgLine'
        });

    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0tfkfh2v/16

Comment: I was able to get average data in desktop chrome browser , but when tried use in mobile chrome browser , I get NAN as avg because sum and count both  evaluate to zero as serie.data = Array[0]. also I get errors while trying to zoom in graph on mobile device . errors are like :  Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
highstock.js:179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartX' of undefined........ thanks

Comment: Set width which you use in the example (previous fiddle)